Changing currency for all currency cells by changing one cell
I have a budget spreadsheet which contains tables that have 3 columns- Expected Income, Actual Income and Difference between the two. The last row of the table is is a total row. I need these tables to be used in £, $ and €.
I currently have a currency dropdown list set up where you can choose from the three currencies. This works perfectly in the Difference column where the following formula is set up - =IF(E9="","", $F$40 & TEXT(E9-D9, "0.00")). This formula is set in the Difference column so that it is empty until data is entered into actual the Actual column but also so that when data is entered it shows as the currency selected from the dropdown list.
My issue is that I am struggling to get the correct formula for the Expected, Actual and Total columns. I need the Expected and Actual Columns to show as empty until data is entered, but when data is entered I need it to show in the currency selected from the dropdown list.
The total columns currently are autosum, I need these to also show as the currency selected from the dropdown list.
Please see table for reference.
I have tried conditional formatting for this but it doesn't seem to work.

PUt just he value and use conditional formatting with 1 rule per monetary type.

If you setup your Conditional Formatting like this (change the cell references to match your sheet) it should work:

Use the Use a formula to determine which cells to format option when creating the rules. After entering your formula, click Format..., select the Number tab, then select Currency. Select the appropriate currency symbol in the Symbol dropdown for each of the rules.
Then just use the actual number values in your cells instead of creating a concatenated string.
Hope this helps!

Hi Rob, thanks but I can't seem to get this to work? Probably because I have switched the sheet over to Google Sheets so maybe it works differently, though I thought they worked very similarly. Do you know if I would have to tweak this to work in Google sheets? I currently have the below set up in conditional formatting but none of the selected cells change when I change the currency in the dropdown list.

Format cells if... Custom formula is... =$G$40="€"

And exactly the same for £ and $, I cannot work out where I'm going wrong!

@RJD123 sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Google Sheets to give you advice there. The above will work in Excel.
